# questions about the while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I'm trying to get better at while loops. I don't quite understand the (true) value the while loop is referring to here.

```
let str = 'As sly as a fox, as strong as an ox';

let target = 'as'; // let's look for it

let pos = 0;
while (true) {
  let foundPos = str.indexOf(target, pos);
  if (foundPos == -1) break;

  alert( `Found at ${foundPos}` );
  pos = foundPos + 1; // continue the search from the next position
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` means loop forever, unless the loop is broken from the inside. You could alternatively say `while (foundPos > -1)` but then you'd have to define `foundPos` outside of the loop and give it an appropriate value too, for the loop to even take place at all.

Comment: @AngelPolitis got it thanks!